# Using sDNA to analyze the network downloaded from OSM, do we need to merge the network first？

Tags: openstreetmap, sdna

In the road network downloaded from OSM, each road is divided into small sections. I would like to know whether I need to merge the sections of the road network of the same road into a complete road before using SDNA to analyze the road network. What tools to use if necessary?

Answer (score 1):

The reference for this is the 'network preparation' chapter of the sDNA manual https://sdna-open.readthedocs.io/en/latest/network_preparation.html

In short

1. check your OSM downloaded network is in endpoint connectivity format. OSM natively uses a shared point rule so depending on what processing was already done by your download tool/site/app/etc, you may need to use a shared point line breaker (such as GRASS v.clean bpol) to make the network usable by sDNA.
2. Whether you join smaller sections to a larger link is up to you. If you do, it will potentially process much faster (if you reduce the effective link count by a large amount). sDNA Prepare can do this for you ('fix split links' option). However if you need results at finer resolution than individual links then you can break links into as many segments as you like - sDNA will just be slower to run.